# Cython can cast int 65 into char 'A'?

Tags: python, cython

```
%%cython
import cython
cdef int k = 65
cdef unsigned char kk = cython.cast("char", k)
print kk
```

the result is 65. I already tried `<char>` to convert 65 to 'A'

Anyone have some ideas? I am currently working in Ipython notebook.

Thank you in advance!!

[Edited]
I added the first motivation to this question.

In c,

```
int i = 65;
char c = i;
printf("%c", c); //prints 'A'
```

because char 'A' is already int, if I correctly understand

But in Cython,

```
%%cython
import cython
cdef int k = 65
cdef char kk = cython.cast("char", k) 
print <char>kk, <int>kk
```

same result.

Comment: I also tried "from libc.stdlib cimport atoi" to check the type strictly, it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int to ASCII and back in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673428/convert-int-to-ascii-and-back-in-python)

Comment: Try `kk = <int>k`?

Comment: @TomWyllie I don't think so. That has nothing to do with cython?

Comment: Well, um, 65 is the integer value of 'A'. Characters are (usually) signed, 8-byte integers. I'm not seeing what the issue is here: just a lack of understanding of what a char is.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Could you kindly explain something more? I expected that `%%cython
cdef int k = 65;
print <char>k;` is 'A', thinking about chr(97) is 'a' in python.

Comment: @KimSungHyun, I wrote a trivial answer to explain how this works, and why I believe Cython's behavior is correct, even if counter-intuitive. Remember, everything is just bytes under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't have true character types. Python has strings. The `ord()` function works by taking a 1-character string as a function argument, and just throws an error if the string's length is longer.

Under the hood, all `ord()` really does is just cast the `char` to `int`. In C, I could write a naive function like this:

```c
#include <string.h>         // for strlen

int c_ord(const char* string)
{
    // declare our variables
    size_t length;
    int ret;

    // check the length
    // note that Python actually stores the length,
    // so this wouldn't be done in real code.
    // This is here for example
    length = strlen(string);
    if (length != 1) {
        // invalid length, set a dummy placeholder
        ret = -1; 
    } else {
        // just grab our value
        ret = string[0];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Notice how all `ord()` is doing is getting the exact value, just getting the character, not the string representation. What Cython is doing is the true behavior: treating char like an integer and therefore printing out it's integer value. To treat a character like a string, we could create a array of characters, and let Python know it's a string. The builtin method `chr` does this for us all under the hood.

```py
%%cython
import cython
cdef int k = 65
print chr(k)
```

To write a trivial method in Cython to create a null-terminated C-string, and optionally convert it to a Python string, we can do the following:

Python doesn't have true character types. Python has strings. The `ord()` function works by taking a 1-character string as a function argument, and just throws an error if the string's length is longer.

Under the hood, all `ord()` really does is just cast the `char` to `int`. In C, I could write a naive function like this:

```c
#include <string.h>         // for strlen

int c_ord(const char* string)
{
    // declare our variables
    size_t length;
    int ret;

    // check the length
    // note that Python actually stores the length,
    // so this wouldn't be done in real code.
    // This is here for example
    length = strlen(string);
    if (length > 1) {
        // invalid length, set a dummy placeholder
        ret = -1; 
    } else {
        // just grab our value
        ret = string[0];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Notice how all `ord()` is doing is getting the exact value, just getting the character, not the string representation. What Cython is doing is the true behavior: treating char like an integer and therefore printing out it's integer value. To treat a character like a string, we could create a array of characters, and let Python know it's a string. The builtin method `chr` does this for us all under the hood.

```py
%%cython
import cython
cdef int k = 65
print chr(k)
```

To write a trivial extension to do `chr()` and create a null-terminated string (commonly referred to as a C-string), we can write the following.

```py
%%cython
# imports
import cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

# create null-terminated string, or a C-string
cdef char* c_string = <char*>malloc(2)      # only need 2
c_string[0] = 65                            # 'A'
c_string[1] = 0                             # '\0', null-termination
# ... do what we want with the C-string

# convert to Python object
cdef bytes str = c_string

# remember to free the allocate memory
free(c_string)

# use Python object
print(str)
```

Comment: Grab some coffee. Good answer overall.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Thank you! Meanwhile, I am writing hash fucntion in cython using openMP. That's why python version `chr` should be avoided `with no-gil` openMP implementation. According to your answer, it seems better to write another helper function to work this way...

Comment: @KimSungHyun, it would be pretty trivial to do so since you just need a simple extension to do so, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @danny, because we don't have a Python byte string, apparently?

Comment: Yup, shouldn't post before coffee apparently :)