# What does the name of the ord() function stand for?

Tags: python, unicode, built-in, ordinal, ord

The official Python documentation explains `ord(c)`

> ord(c):
>   Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 and ord('€') (Euro sign) returns 8364. This is the inverse of chr().

It does not specify the meaning of `ord`, google searches are not helpful.

What's the origin of it?

Comment: It stands for “ordinal”. The ordinal here is the number representing the position of c in the sequence of Unicode codepoints. The name dates back… a while.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data_type

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It stands for ["ordinal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data_type).

The earliest use of `ord` that I remember was in [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)). There, `ord()` returned the ordinal value of its argument. For characters this was defined as the ASCII code.

The same convention was also used in [Modula-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-2).

Later, Python (as well as PHP, some dialects of SQL etc) followed this convention, except that these days they're more likely to use Unicode rather than ASCII.

It could well be that the origins of the term (and the function name) go back further than Pascal.

Answer (score 5):

"ord" meaning "**ordinal** of a one character".

I took this from using `ord.__doc__` in the Python command line.

> Return the integer **ordinal** of a one-character string.

Comment: Python 3.12 it says 'Return the Unicode code point for a one-character string.'