# Is there a good python library that can turn numbers into their respective "symbols"?

Tags: python, numbers, computer-science, int, radix

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
...
9 = 9
10 = a
11 = b
...
35 = z
36 = A
37 = B
...
60 = Z
61 = 10
62 = 11
... 
70 = 19
71 = 1a
72 = 1b
```

I don't know what this is called. Base something?

All I want is a function that can convert the numbers into these, and these back to numbers.

Is there an easy function that can do this?

Comment: Looks like base 61. I doubt there are any common libraries that use base 61.

Comment: This is really hard to read.  Please put some newlines in your code block.

Comment: How do you know if it's base 62 or base 61?

Comment: It's 61, not 62. Reading directly from the question... `61 = 10`. Also, 9 + 26 + 26 == 61.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may inherit numbers.Number:

```
def baseN(base,alphabet='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
    class _baseN(numbers.Number):
        digits=alphabet[:base]
        def __init__(self,value):
            if isinstance(value,int):
                self.value=value
                if self.value==0:
                    self.string='0'
                else:
                    tmp=[abs(value)]
                    while tmp[0]!=0:
                        tmp[:1]=divmod(tmp[0],base)
                    tmp=[alphabet[i] for i in tmp]
                    tmp[0]='-' if self.value<0 else ''
                    self.string=''.join(tmp)
            elif isinstance(value,str):
                assert(value.isalnum())
                self.string=str(value)
                self.value=0
                for d in value:
                    self.value=self.value*base+self.digits.index(d)
            else:
                self.value=0
                self.string='0'
        def __int__(self):
            return self.value
        def __str__(self):
            return self.string
        def __repr__(self):
            return self.string
        def __add__(self,another):
            return self.__class__(self.value+int(another))
    return None if base>len(alphabet) else _baseN
```

Found another bug. Change it to a factory function. Now may handle general situation.

Comment: Whoops, made a mistake about turning int to string, fixed now.

Comment: import string; string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> int("a", 36)
10
>>> int("z", 36)
35
>>> int("10", 36)
36
```

The other direction is more complicated, but try [this ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65212-convert-from-decimal-to-any-base-number/).

Normally base conversions make no distinction between cases.  I'm not sure how to completely extend this to make that distinction, but the recipe should give you a start.