# Can someone help me on why this python script won't run?

Tags: python, debugging

```
import numbers

class base62(numbers.Number):
    digits='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    def __init__(self,value):
        if isinstance(value,int):
            self.value=value
            if value==0:
                self.string='0'
            else:
                self.string='' if value>0 else '-'
                while value!=0:
                    value,d=divmod(value,62)
                    self.string=self.digits[d]+self.string
        elif isinstance(value,(str,bytes)):
            assert(value.isalnum())
            self.string=str(value)
            self.value=0
            for d in value:
                self.value=self.value*62+self.digits.index(d)
    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
    def __str__(self):
        return self.string
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.string


Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import base62
>>> b = base62(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: There are some bugs in this function, so I rewrote it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351467/is-there-a-good-python-library-that-can-turn-numbers-into-their-respective-symbo/4351612#4351612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base62` appears to be the name of both your module and your function inside that module. Try:

```
>>> import base62
>>> b = base62.base62(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message:

`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

`TypeError` means there was an `Error` because something was of the wrong `Type`. The thing in question is `base62`. This is because `base62` is the name of your `module`, which is not a `callable` thing. "callable", as it sounds, means "able to be called".

The thing you want to call is the function defined **in** the module. The function is also named `base62`, but the function is not available by that name, because right now that name represents the module.

Fortunately, functions in a module are represented as attributes of the module. Thus, you can access it as `base62.base62`: the `base62` attribute (the **second** one in that syntax) of whatever `base62` (first one) is. In this case, the `base62` function in the `base62` module.

Alternately, you can import only that function from the module, by telling Python what to import from the module. That is written naturally, but not in the order you might expect: you write it as `from base62 import base62`. (Again, the module name -what you're importing from - comes first, and the function name - what's being imported from it - second.)

Comment: The OP isn't big on reading things, like documentation, either.