# Python how to shorten a uuuid and decode?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a shortened ID for one of my models using the following method:

```
_char_map = string.ascii_letters+string.digits

def index_to_char(sequence):
    return "".join([_char_map[x] for x in sequence])

    def make_short_id(self):
        _id = self.id
        digits = []
        while _id > 0:
            rem = _id % 62
            digits.append(rem)
            _id /= 62
        digits.reverse()
        return index_to_char(digits) 

    @staticmethod
    def decode_id(string):
        i = 0
        for c in string:
            i = i * 64 + _char_map.index(c)
        return i
```

Where `self.id` is a uuid i.e. `1c7a2bc6-ca2d-47ab-9808-1820241cf4d4`, but I get the following error:

> rem = _id % 62
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

This method only seems to work when the `id` is an `int`.

How can I modify the method to shorten a uuuid and decode?

UPDATE:

Thank you for the help. I was trying to find a way create an encode and decode method that took a string, made it shorter then decode it back again. The methods above can never work with a string (uuid) as pointed out,

Comment: Hi are you trying to cut the id into pieces?

Comment: Hi @MaximilianKindshofer I'm trying to shorten the uuid to xxx then decode it back at the other end to the same uuid.

Comment: You cannot do modulus operations on a string of characters.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I see so this is not going to work then as my uuid contains strings, oops. Guess I have to try and find a way to encode and decode a string to something shorter as this only works with numbers then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`%`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) operator is the string formatting or interpolation operator and does not return the remainder in Python when used with strings. It will try to return a formatted string instead.

I'm not sure what your input is, but try converting it using `int` so you can get the remainder of it.

Edit: I see your input now, not sure why I missed it. Here's one method of converting a UUID to a number:

```
import uuid
input = "1c7a2bc6-ca2d-47ab-9808-1820241cf4d4"
id = uuid.UUID(input)
id.int
# returns 37852731992078740357317306657835644116L
```

Not sure what you mean by "shorten", but it looks like you are trying to "base 62 encode" the UUID. If you use the function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119769/98057) you will end up with the following:

```
uuid62 = base62_encode(id.int)
# uuid62 contains 'RJChvUCPWDvJ7BdQKOw7i'
```

To get the original UUID back:

```
# Create a UUID again
id = uuid.UUID(int=base62_decode(uuid62))

id.hex
# returns '1c7a2bc6ca2d47ab98081820241cf4d4'           

str(id)
# returns '1c7a2bc6-ca2d-47ab-9808-1820241cf4d4'
```

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but the input is a uuid as in the OP, how can this be converted to an int?

Comment: I was only looking at how the input is _handled_ in the question. The OP is trying to convert a number by repeatedly doing remainder/division so I assumed that it was some sort of number.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. I will have to find a way to encode and decode a string to something shorter with a different method. Thanks for your help

Comment: I recommend against using `id` as a variable name unless you want to override builtin `id()`.

Answer (score 2):

`_id` is string

```
>>> 11 % 2
1

>>> "11" % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()` from the standard library, rather than rolling your own `base62_encode()` function.

You first need to convert your hex string to a binary string:

```
binary_id = id.replace("-", "").decode("hex")
```

This binary string can the be encoded using the afore-mentioned function:

```
shortened_id = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(binary_id)
```