# Generating seemingly random looking unique numbers for url purposes

Tags: python, database, algorithm, base64, uniqueidentifier

So I was wondering about youtube's url. Specially the video id `watch?v=XZmGGAbHqa0`. Same for similar tinyurl services.

I came across Tom's video of [Will YouTube Ever Run Out Of Video IDs?](https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8) That was quite interesting. But generating a seemingly random number in a random way, check for duplicates looked quite expensive.

In case you haven't watched the video, youtube generates a large unique number and base64 encode it. Not sure if the whole process is that simple inside youtube but I'm trying to write something similar.

I came across a mathematical function called `Modular Multiplicative Inverse.` Using this along with a bit of **Extended Euclidean algorithm** will generate a unique number from our given input. Inverse is possible too, But someone won't be easily able to inverse or brute force without knowing the seeds. So we can easily get a large random number from our subsequent id in database. Maybe even base64 it.

But I have confusions.

As tom mentioned in the video, syncing a subsequent id across multiple servers can lead to problems and overheads. But if we don't make it subsequent, won't it be a tedious and expensive task to find a unique id? We have to check if the id is available in db.

Should I avoid mixing in url with subsequent ids? Or masking it with something like that Multiplicative Inverse is good?

Why would I want to base64 it? To save storage or to save url space? I would still need to generate something seemingly random, unique and be able to quickly generate it without duplicating and search it.

Any better ways to achieve what I'm trying? I did checked all the similar so questions and a few blog posts. On of which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442875/what-is-the-algorithm-of-youtubes-for-generating-video-slugs)

Sorry If I couldn't explain well, I'm quite confused what to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you bypass the issue of ensuring uniqueness of randomly generated numbers entirely and use a pseudorandom permutation (PRP) family to transform a pre-coordinated counter.

A PRP family is like a PRF family in that it is a cipher that takes a key and a plaintext and produces a ciphertext except that it has a one-to-one map between plaintexts and ciphertexts.

This lets one use a Twitter Snowflake like design and then simply encode the internal sequential identifiers into non-sequential external identifiers.

See [Algorithm to turn numeric IDs in to short, different alphanumeric codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624017/algorithm-to-turn-numeric-ids-in-to-short-different-alphanumeric-codes) for an implementation in Python.

Also

> M. Luby and C. Rackoff. How to construct pseudorandom permutations from pseudorandom functions. SIAM J. Comput., 17(2):373–386, Apr. 1988.

Comment: interesting.. I found something called UUID too. Learning all these things and things you mentioned.