# Pythonic way to create a big random base-29 number

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, integer, radix

I'm creating a program which has to handle rather big ints in python. Ranging from 0-10<sup>4677</sup>. Internally, I represent them with as `base-29` integers. Thus using the alfabet: `012345679ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS`.

I created a function to create a random `base-29` variable of any length in python. But is there a shorter, more pythonic way possible? (if this is even a proper way of doing it).

The function to create a random base-29 number:

```py
import random

def random_base(base_number = 29, length = 10)
    alfabet = "012345679ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS"
    return [alfabet[random.randint(0,base_number - 1)] for _ in range(length)]
```

Thus, is there some built-in python function to perform this, or is this the way to go?

Please comment if things are unclear!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Seems like you've missed digit `8`

Comment: You could convert *any* random number to base-29 by making a trivial modification to the accepted answer to the question [Base 62 conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119722/base-62-conversion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [slices](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) and [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

```
import random

def random_base(base_number = 29, length = 10):
    alfabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS"
    return "".join(random.choices(alfabet[:base_number], k=length))
```