# Uneven base-36 support in Python?

Tags: python, base36

I've been working with base-36 recently and have never been satisfied with [the usual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181919/python-base-36-encoding) to converting ints into base-36 strings.  It looks a little imbalanced…

```
def to_base36(value):
    if not isinstance(value, int):
        raise TypeError("expected int, got %s: %r" % (value.__class__.__name__, value))

    if value == 0:
        return "0"

    if value < 0:
        sign = "-"
        value = -value
    else:
        sign = ""

    result = []

    while value:
        value, mod = divmod(value, 36)
        result.append("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[mod])

    return sign + "".join(reversed(result))
```

…when compared to converting back…

```
def from_base36(value):
    return int(value, 36)
```

Does Python really not include this particular battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Not every store carries [N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_battery) or [J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes#J) batteries.

Comment: +1, base 36 is rather unusual, so including it in the standard library would just add bloat

Comment: @Rafe — To me, it's less base36 specifically, but that Python includes support for converting *from* arbitrary bases but not *to* them.

Comment: Rafe: Yet it's apparently not so unusual, nor the 'bloat' so bad, to warrant removing from `int()`!

Comment: @Ben yes, that would make sense.

Comment: Standard C has the same asymmetry.

Comment: ... which is probably a big clue as to why Python also has the asymmetry - as much of the original string formatting probably depending on the underlying C libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the [basin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/basin/) package?

```
>>> import basin
>>> basin.encode("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 100)
'2s'
```

It's not batteries included, but the `pypi` repository is like a convenience store for picking up batteries with the minimum of fuss.

Answer (score 1):

To continue the analogy, that size battery may not be included in the basic package, but it's easy enough to shop on-line for plug-compatible accessories:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/365468-number-to-string-in-arbitrary-base/

Comment: Heh, I like your analogy more :)