# Base36 Encode a String?

Tags: java, python, ruby

I've been looking online, but can't find a solution to this.  In Python, Ruby, or Java, how can I base 36 encode the following string:  nOrG9Eh0uyeilM8Nnu5pTywj3935kW+5=

Comment: Encode or decode? It looks encoded.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with cryptography.

Comment: I want to encode that string and then decode it back in Base36.  I just want to know if it's even possible.

Comment: To all the people sharing code to encode a number, thanks, but I'm trying to encode a string.  Please excuse me if that's not possible.  I see libraries that can base 64 encode a string, though.

Comment: @SLaks Encryption also includes algorithms that are hopelessly naive ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ruby

---

*To base 36:*

```
s.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16).to_s 36
```

*From base 36:*

```
[s36.to_i(36).to_s(16)].pack 'H*'
```

Comment: Very nice, DigitalRoss.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have just done this:

```
  static String encodeRootId(final String value) {
    try {
      final BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      final String encoded = bigInteger.toString(Character.MAX_RADIX);

      //must encode the sign as well
      if (bigInteger.signum() < 0) {
        return 'n' + encoded.substring(1);
      } else {
        return 'p' + encoded;
      }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("impossible");
    }
  }
```

the trick to convert the string bytes[] to a big int brought the disadvantage of having to manually encode the possible -, admittedly not pretty but a quick solution.

also, in my use case i dont have to decode and performance is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wikipedia has an article on how to do it in python:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

Answer (score -1):

This could be seen as a duplicate as another question... [Python base 36 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181919/python-base-36-encoding).

Basically, there is this example on wikipedia:

```
def base36encode(number, alphabet='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
    """Convert positive integer to a base36 string."""
    if not isinstance(number, (int, long)):
        raise TypeError('number must be an integer')

    # Special case for zero
    if number == 0:
        return alphabet[0]

    base36 = ''

    sign = ''
    if number < 0:
        sign = '-'
        number = - number

    while number != 0:
        number, i = divmod(number, len(alphabet))
        base36 = alphabet[i] + base36

    return sign + base36

def base36decode(number):
    return int(number, 36)

print base36encode(1412823931503067241)
print base36decode('AQF8AA0006EH')
```

Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

Comment: This answers the question of how to base 36 encode a numeric value, but not a string.

Comment: base36 is about encoding NUMBERS *only*

Comment: @Bradford: Just convert your string to a number and encode it. Reverse the steps for decoding. For example if you're using 8-bit characters, consider each character code to be a Base 256 digit.

Comment: @Bradford: Here's a quick way to convert a string of 8-bit characters into a number: `reduce(lambda a,d: a*256 + ord(d), astring, 0)`.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks a lot martineau.  That's actually the answer I was looking for.  It was easy to reverse with divmod too.