# Python increment string with both letters and numbers

Tags: python, string

I am attempting to increment a string that has both letters and numbers in it - each of the characters in the string can either be 0-9 or a-z, no upper case letters.

Ideally I would hope it could be incremented in a +1 fashion in the sense that if the string was o6 to o7 o8 o9 oa ob etc to oz then p0 p1 etc *by the way that's a lower base O not a zero*

The method I use to increment only works by converting string to int, then incrementing by +1 and cannot be used here.

```
number = str(int(number) + 1)
```

Comment: What happends when you get to zz?

Comment: So, you only want to increment the second character? And what happens for a `9` or `z`?

Comment: Oh, I see - you basically want to count in base 36.

Comment: I appreciate you greatly tigerhawk - the duplicate you found was part of what I needed, in defining baseencode and decode for 36 - but the answer is listed below as number = base36encode(base36decode(number) + 1) ty though for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181919/python-base-36-encoding) shows you how to do base36 encoding/decoding in Python.

To increment a number that is encoded in base36, you just decode it to an integer, add 1, then encode the result.

```
number = base36encode(base36decode(number) + 1)
```

Comment: Your answer did it for me - the duplicate helped me define the two and number = base36encode(base36decode(number) + 1) did the rest, thanks so much