# Convert base 36 value to base 10 value

Tags: python

How can I convert a base 36 value to base 10?

Base 36 value: `lgzl0`

We need to convert this value to 36064548.

Are there any built-in functions to convert base values?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181919/python-base-36-encoding

Comment: @0stone0 which of these answers are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your base is 36 and not 26 (numbers from 0 to 9 and letters from a to z) as there is a 'z' and a '0' (zero) in the number you want to convert. You can use the `int` function:

```py
>>> int("lgzl0", base=36)
36064548
```