# Converting integer to a 4 letter encoded string

Tags: python, backend

I have seen websites generate short urls, where they convert IDs for items into a 4 letter string. Here's an example: https://boxd.it/nrI0

This is for a website called Letterboxd, and the link takes you to a movie page. I'm guessing behind the scenes the movie has an integer ID that is then converted into this 4 letter string (or maybe its stored as that 4 letter value to begin with?)

How is this accomplished?

Comment: You ask how is it accomplish in such specific case or in general?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an integer to the shortest url-safe string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561486/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-the-shortest-url-safe-string-in-python)

Comment: @kosciej16 In this specific case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are many options to do this. But in most cases there is no direct relation between integer ID and generated slug for short URL. I am pretty sure this case is not exception. I suppose they just generate random 4 letter string that never used before and maintain relation between film and short URL at the database level.

Comment: Could you backup your sentence 'in most cases'? I think the opposite and have an idea how to check it in this case.

Comment: @kosciej16 You can think of many options to get 4 letter string from integer. @Arne already gave an example. It can also be any hash-solution (for instance, `md5`), but  using only 4 letters of hash (need some more specific logic to avoid collisions in specific case).

But if you don't have any insider information, it will be very hard too guess :)